# Hiding multiple elements & adding styles using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can only use JavaScript to edit my checkout page, I am trying to hide and add styles to multiple elements using the least amount of characters.

Here's an example of one of the elements.

```
<div class="section section--remember-me shown-if-js">

<div class="content-box__row content-box__row--tight-spacing-vertical content-box__row--secondary">
```

Also trying to change the width of a button and make sure that the class.

```
<div class="step__footer" data-step-footer="">
```

This the parent of where the button is located in, and I want to make sure that the text thats also in this div isn't next to the button, but under it so I think I have to add style="display: inline-block;"

The button class is called

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn ">
```

This is the code I have so far. I haven't been able to get it to hide multiple elements yet.

```html
if (document.querySelector('.section--example') !== null) {
if (!element.classList.contains('example1')) {
    element.classList.add('hidden');
};
document.getElementById("step__footer__continue-btn").style.width = "100%";
};
```

Comment: if (document.querySelector('.section--example') !== null) {  --- this part is because this code should only execute if this section exists on the page

Comment: I think you want to use `.querySelectorAll()` and loop over the Array Like Object of Elements, in vanilla JS, or just `$('.classNameHere')` to work with `.each()` in jQuery.

Comment: If I could add "hidden" to the <div class="section"> of this specific section but not any other ones that would be cool but if not, the third div will still work. https://i.imgur.com/1Xf1dN5.jpg

Comment: Sorry but this question is a mess. Could you please provide a complete example of the relevant code (HTML + JS) and tell us what exactly you want to achieve and what you've tried.

Comment: Okay, I am trying to optimize the checkout proccess on my website by removing elements that aren't necessary and I want to increase the size of the complete checkout button. I don't have access to the the checkout page, but I can add javascript that runs during the checkout. There's three pages that people see and I wanted to make sure this script didn't run unless they were on the last page.

Comment: if (document.querySelector('.section--payment-method') !== null) {
document.querySelectorAll("content-box__row--secondary, remembermebox").forEach(hide);
};

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1Xf1dN5.jpg Trying to hide this div

Answer (score 0):

if-blocks do not need semicolons btw

```
document.querySelectorAll(".section--example:not(.example1)").forEach(hide);

function hide(element) {
    element.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

Comment: if (document.querySelector('.section--example') !== null) {
};  --  Im using this to make sure this part of the script only executes on a specific page. Is theres a better way to make sure this only runs if its on the specific page with these elements?

Comment: I'm unsure of your point, but the fact remains that semicolons do not belong at the end of an if-block.

Answer (score 0):

To effect all element in an HTML class in jQuery it's like:

```
$(function(){
  $('.sectionExample').css('background', '#000;');    
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
  $('.sectionExample').each(function(increment, element){
    var current = $(element);
    current.css('background', '#000;');
    // this way is more versatile, if working with other Elements
  });    
});
```